# Child Theme of a Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a child theme of a [proficient](https://wordpress.org/themes/proficient/) theme (that is a child of [specia](https://wordpress.org/themes/specia/))

I created a "proficient-child" folder and created style.css and functions.php with modifications.

I put this code to load parent style:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' ); 

function enqueue_parent_styles() { 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' ); 
}
```

But the template is loading the Specia CSS, not the Proficient...

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you've done step 2 on this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#2-create-a-stylesheet-style-css)

Comment: I thought creating child themes of child themes wasn’t even possible in WordPress …?

Comment: @misorude it is possible, but to meant to be done: https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/gridmarket-can-you-make-a-child-theme-of-a-child-theme

Comment: According to [This](https://docs.appthemes.com/tutorials/creating-grandchild-themes/) It's also possible, but it's not really a grandchild theme in a traditional sence.

Comment: Better create a grandchild theme, as plugin, see here: https://www.wp-code.com/wordpress-snippets/wordpress-grandchildren-themes/